# Do not understand error in if-else section

Tags: ibm-q-experience, programming

I have tried to build a circuit for encryption.
One function is:

```
def selector(qc, a, b, c):
    qc.measure(a, 0)
    if a == 1:
        qc.cswap(a, b, c)
    else:
        qc.id(b)
        qc.id(c)
```

When I run it in IBM quantum lab, only the else option appears to be working. Why is my `a == 1` case never taking place?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is always takes the else branch because you are branching on `a == 1` where `a` is `0` (as you mentioned in [your comment](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/32109/do-not-understand-error-in-if-else-section#comment42434_32111) `selector(fcircuit,0,1,2)`).

I have the feeling that you are confusing circuit construction and execution time. In your code `measure` runs at circuit-execution-time, while your conditional is at circuit-construction-time.

Running a conditional at execution time requires dynamic circuits. In this case:

```python
qc.measure(a, 0)                  # measures a into classical bit 0
with qc.if_test((0, 0)) as else_: # tests if classical bit 0 is 0
    qc.cswap(a, b, c)             # then branch
with else_:
    qc.id(b)                      # else branch
    qc.id(c)                      #
```

This condition (`if_test`) is not a Python branching, but a conditional that will run as the circuit is being executed.

Comment: thank you. need to understand more on it.

Answer (score 0):

When you say only the else is working, I assume you mean the `cswap` is never taking place.
In your code, you compare `a` to 1, while a is a qubit identifier. What you need to check is the classical register bit to which the measurement has been saved.

`qc.measure(a, 0)` [essentially means](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.measure.html) "measure qubit a and save the result to classical bit 0".

When you initialized your qc, you have either specified your classical register (in which case you can check its value under index 0 after the measurement) or you can use `qc.clbits` to see the classical bits of the circuit (see [docs](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.html).)

Your code then becomes something like `if qc.clbits[0] == 1`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this. But the circuit returns the same. def selector(qc,a,b,c):
    qc.measure(a,0)
    if qc.clbits[0] == 1:
        qc.swap(b,c)
    else:
        qc.id(b)
        qc.id(c)

Comment: My main circuit like : qreg_q = QuantumRegister(3, 'q')
creg_c = ClassicalRegister(3, 'c')
fcircuit = QuantumCircuit(qreg_q, creg_c)
fcircuit.x(qreg_q[2])
fcircuit.x(qreg_q[0])
#fcircuit.x(qreg_q[0])
for i in range(3):
    fcircuit.barrier(i)
selector(fcircuit,0,1,2)
for i in range(3):
    fcircuit.measure(i,i)
fcircuit.draw()

Comment: Could you paste your code into the original question and we can try and sort it out?